# Demuxer : Unconnected Wires / firrtl error

Tags: chisel

I am trying to make a demuxer using Chisel but the code fails to compile and throw this error shown in the imgur link

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW0Rv.png)

```
class Demuxer extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val datain = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val dataout1 = Output(UInt(8.W))
    val dataout2 = Output(UInt(8.W))
    val dataout3 = Output(UInt(8.W))
    val dataout4 = Output(UInt(8.W))
    val dataout5 = Output(UInt(8.W))  
    val selector = Input((UInt(3.W)))  
  })
  when(io.selector === 1.U){
        io.dataout1 := io.datain
  }.elsewhen(io.selector === 2.U){
      io.dataout2 := io.datain
  }.elsewhen(io.selector === 3.U){
      io.dataout3 := io.datain
  }.elsewhen(io.selector === 4.U){
      io.dataout4 := io.datain
  }.elsewhen(io.selector === 5.U){
      io.dataout5 := io.datain
  }.otherwise{
       
  }
}
```

I read the wiki about unconnected element
https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/wiki-deprecated/unconnected-wires.html

If I use use io.outs <> DontCare on my IO, the code compiles but the generated verilog shorts my inputs to all the outputs, which is not the desired behaviour I want from this module. Can any one suggest I fix to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chisel and the Scala FIRRTL Compiler require that all outputs are driven in all cases. This helps avoid bugs where a designer forgets to drive some port/wire/reg. The issue is that the code needs to set some default value (or use `DontCare`) for all of the module outputs.

When you set all the outputs to `DontCare` usually one of two things will happen:

1. The default connection will be `0.U`.
2. The default connection will be some other legal value or connection.

(2) is what is happening here. When you write `io.dataout1 := DontCare`, you're indicating to the compiler that it can set this to anything. The compiler is then choosing to set this to `io.dataout1 := io.datain` (shorting the input to the output).

Instead of using `DontCare` you can use something explicit, e.g., `0.U` will create a mux for each output. Doing this with one line looks like:

```scala
  Seq(io.dataout1, io.dataout2, io.dataout3, io.dataout4, io.dataout5).foreach(
    _ := 0.U
  )
```

Comment: thanks so much for the pointer, adding that line of code enabled my module to be compiled.